# SharePoint task assign email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, workflow-tasks-list, task-assignment

I have a workflow where clients submit their expense requests, and it goes along with 2/3 attachments.  The client completes the form in the list and add the invoice + quotes.  Then the workflow assigns a task to the manager to approve.

The standard email goes out that shows the link to the task, the description and related items.

I would like to edit that email, is that possible?

If possible, how can I add the attachments that was added to the form as links in the email?

Also how do I change the layout of that standard email?

What I would like to achieve is to change the standard email that is send out to the 'assigned to' person:

[image]

Comment: Which workflow you are using, 2010/2013?  Which action you are using to assign the tasks from workflow?

Comment: I use the 2013 workflow and I use 'assign task' step in the workflow

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow, while using `Assign a task` action you can edit the email body as per your requirements.

Follow below steps:

1. Click on `this user`(see in below image) to open the properties of Assign a task action.
2. Scroll down and expand the **Email Options**.
3. Click on **Open email editor**.
4. One pop up will open. Here you can edit the email body as per your requirements.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh, I did that, but I want to add a link directly to the attachments in that mail. Currently you have to click on 'related items', that opens up the item that was created in the SharePoint library and you have to scroll down and open the attachments from there. The client wants to open the related items directly from the mail.

Comment: Check [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94ee82f7-31f3-474e-b10a-a1f6d8c12235/workflow-get-item-that-is-related-to-the-current-task?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy) similar question and let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: I've edited my question, it shows the message/email I want to change

Comment: First of all try to get the original item ID of your list item(expense request) then you can achieve something like this using [Rest API in workflow](https://sshareasolutions.com/2017/09/20/sharepoint-list-attachment-url-in-email-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow-and-rest-api/).

Comment: Or you can try setting workflow variable to `Current Item: Attachments` and then use that variable in your Email body (I have not tried this).

Comment: I've tried the Current Item: Attachements in my email body, but it returns 'True' if there are attachments and 'False' if there are not attachements - it does not include or show a link to the attachments.  I'll try the Rest API solution, it might work

Comment: Yes, try using REST API in your workflow. somewhat difficult but it will work definitely.